# Does it make sense to subtract two partial correlations?

Tags: r, correlation, partial-correlation

I have one continuous variable measured in 3 different populations, A, B & C. This variable contains 5,000 measurements ¿paired? in each of the 3 populations.

I would expect the populations A & B being highly correlated. I would expect C being equally different from both A & B, or slightly more different from B than from A.

A simple (Pearson) correlation shows, though:

```
cor A ~ B: 0.65
cor A ~ C: 0.16
cor B ~ C: 0.55
```

A and B are correlated as predicted (maybe less than I expected), but the association with C is completely the opposite of what I expected. Spearman and Kendall correlations show similar patterns with different values.

I ran a partial correlation between A, B and C using R ppcor package. This gives:

```
part. cor A ~ B (by C): 0.67
part. cor A ~ C (by B): -0.30
part. cor B ~ C (by A): 0.59
```

This points to an even greater difference in the correlations with C when corrected by the correlation between A & B.

I now need to decompose this variable into 100 sub-variables (A1, A2, ..., A100; B1, B2, ..., B100; C1, C2, ..., C100. 5000 measurements for each). I want to detect which of these sub-variables are leading this different correlation between A~C and B~C.

I was thinking on measuring the partial correlations between A~C and B~C of each of these 100 sub-variables. Then subtract A~C - B~C, to see which variables have higher differences in their correlations.

Does this make any sense? Is it a shoddy method? Will I be biasing everything? Will this overestimate the partial correlations and give very high significance to variables where A~B as a high weight in them? Should I do it, but just using the normal correlations instead of the partial? Is there any "better" formal method to test which of these 100 variables are leading this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Values, datasets, variables, subcomponents...you've used terminology in ways that some would call nonstandard and others would call incorrect.  Editing your post by tightening up your use of terms might help draw the most useful answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried tightening my terminology in terms of variables, measurements and populations. I don't know if now it has become more clear or more confusing, though...